# I cannot seem to get GALFIT installed on my computer

Tags: ubuntu, installation, tar

I downloaded the code provided on the GALFIT website for debian/ubuntu 32. I then decompressed it, so it is just a folder with "galfit" being the only thing inside of it.

When I look up "how to install GALFIT", people say that the next step is to cd into the "galfit" directory. But I do not have a galfit directory. I just have a file entitled "galfit" and it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYi5K.png

If I click on this file, nothing happens. I am at a loss as to what I should do next. Can someone tell me what step I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

That `galfit` file IS your binary.

- Mark it as executable
- Make sure your user has permissions to it
- Run it.

> How to do these things?

1. Open a terminal
2. type `cd <path to file here>` for instance `cd /home/swansonalaina/`.  This will be the path you unzipped the file to.
3. type `chmod +x ./galfit` and try that.
4. If you don't get an error, type `./galfit` to run the exe.
5. If you DO get an error, type `sudo chmod +x ./galfit`, then `sudo chown <your user name> ./galfit`.  It will ask you for your password.
6. Try again.

The `chmod +x` command changes the permissions of the file to allow execution.
The `chown BOB ./filename` changes the owner of the file to belong to BOB.
The `sudo` prefix on commands forces the commands to be run as "root" aka "superuser" aka "Administrator"

[If you downloaded the correct file](https://users.obs.carnegiescience.edu/peng/work/galfit/galfit3-debian64.tar.gz), it should run just fine.

It doesn't look like it has and installer (or even need one).

Good luck! :)

Comment: I am extremely new to all of this- what do you mean by mark it as executable?

Comment: No problems!  Files have permissions associated with them.  I don't have Gnome (which is what that looks like to me) but you *probably* will right click that file you have a screen shot of and select `properties` (or similar).. and hunt around in there for "executable" with an option to check a box.  I myself would do it from the terminal.  If you plan on using Linux much,

Comment: Instructions updated, don't be intimidated :)  We all had to learn this stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now!

Comment: Awesome! :)  Feel free to mark this as the correct answer.